# Get Root Directory Path of a PHP project

Tags: php

I have this folder structure in my PHP project.
(this is as shown in eclips)

```
-MySystem
    +Code
    +Data_Access
    -Public_HTML
        +css
        +js
        +Templates
    -resources
```

When I try this code

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

output is

> D:/workspace

How can I get the path to RootDirectory of the system (`MySystem`), without hardcoding the Folder Name?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

For **PHP >= 5.3.0** try

PHP [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

```
__DIR__
```

And make your path relative.

For **PHP < 5.3.0** try

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: this is just awesome, I tried $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], dirname(), $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] etc. but this worked excellently!

Comment: It does depends where you use `__DIR__ ` . It is relative to the file itself, so if in an include, inside a sub directory, it'll not return just your root directory.

Comment: It will not give root directory

Comment: quick note for anyone that stumbles across this answer looking for the answer of the asked question, __DIR__ gets the directory of the current file not the project root unless you call it in a file that is in the project root, but as php doesn't have the concept of a project all paths have to be absolute or  relative to the current location

Comment: Please do not upvote an answer that does not address correctly the question, just because it helped you.

Comment: $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Comment: This solution does NOT return the root directory. It returns the dir of the file it's run from within. This answer is totally useless and misleading!

Answer (score 105):

When you say that

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

contains this path:

```
D:/workspace
```

Then `D:` is what you are looking for, isn't it?
In that case you could explode the string by slashes and return the first one:

```
$pathInPieces = explode('/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
echo $pathInPieces[0];
```

This will output the server's root directory.

**Update:** When you use the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of the hardcoded slash (`'/'`) this code is also working under Windows.

**Update 2:** The `$_SERVER` global variable is not always available. On command line (cli) for example. So you should use `__DIR__` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. `__DIR__` returns the path of the php file itself.

Comment: And you could use `__DIR__` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: Sorry If I have not explained my question properly, What I actually need is 'D:/workspace/MySystem'

Comment: if your root directory path is in the form of /var/public/www" then using this method the first string in the array will be empty (0)/(1)/(2)/(3). the root will be the second string $pathInPieces[1]

Answer (score 36):

use the PHP function:

[`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Gets the current working directory.

Comment: This returns CURRENT executing file path. Not root path

Answer (score 14):

I want to point to the way Wordpress handles this:

```
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
```

As Wordpress is very heavy used all over the web and also works fine locally I have much trust in this method. You can find this definition on the bottom of your wordpress `wp-config.php` file

Comment: I guess this only works when you have two levels of directories. Right? I mean, when call it from base_project_directory/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.php it doesn't return the base_project_directory.

Comment: "As Wordpress is very heavy used all over the web and also works fine locally I have much trust in this method."

I don't believe this is a particularly good argument given the WP code quality and security track record.

Comment: @AlexBarker I would contest the fact your implying that WP has a bad security track record. It's actually pretty secure and has a respinsive team focused on secuity - core has had very few exploited security issues in recent years (including as far back as when you commented).

Comment: actually this doesn't work. Didn't investigate too much, but it looks like the double `dirname` actually strips a directory out (probably not what people who come to this thread want -> i.e. me)

Comment: @43matthew You're right. Past then it worked this way but obviously not anymore. As WP also changed the definition I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 11):

At this moment, PHP itself does not provide a way to get the project's root directory for sure.

But you can implement a very simple method yourself that will do exactly what you're looking for.

**Solution**

Create a new file in your project, let say `D:/workspace/MySystem/Code/FilesManager.php` (use whatever name and path suit you the best). Then, use the following code:

```
<?php

class FilesManager
{
  public static function rootDirectory()
  {
    // Change the second parameter to suit your needs
    return dirname(__FILE__, 2);
  }
}
```

Now you can do this in, let's say `D:/workspace/MySystem/Code/a/b/c/Feature.php`:

```
echo FilesManager::rootDirectory();
```

And the expected result should be:

```
"D:/workspace/MySystem"
```

The output will be the same no matter where your "feature" file is located in the project.

**Explanation**

[dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) is used to return the parent directory of the first parameter. We use the [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` to give it `FilesManager.php`'s path. The second parameter tells how many times to go up in the hierarchy. In this case, we need to do it twice, but it really depends where you put your file in the hierarchy. You can omit the second parameter if you only need to got up once, meaning the file is located in the root. But then, you can return `__DIR__` directly instead.

This solution is guaranteed to work, no matter where the root is located on your server. Unless you end up moving the utility class somewhere else in the hierarchy.

**Additional note**

I'd avoid using DOCUMENT_ROOT for the following reasons (according to this [answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/2178)):

- It makes your application dependent on the server.
- The Apache setup may give an incorrect path to the root directory.

Comment: the second argument for `dirname` helped a lot

Comment: I tried your solution and it works on localhost , but when I used it on my host there are additional /\ added to the url ,

Answer (score 5):

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

is useful but will get the current path relative to the current file URL you in incase you are in other directory far from root like includes and you need get folder from the root you can use integer parameter 2 will go 1 level up and so on

```
echo dirname(__FILE__, 2);
```

before

[C:\laragon\www\x\includes\reports\charts](http://C:%5Claragon%5Cwww%5Cx%5Cincludes%5Creports%5Ccharts)

after

[C:\laragon\www\x\reports\charts](http://C:%5Claragon%5Cwww%5Cx%5Creports%5Ccharts)

reports is folder inside the root directory x

Answer (score 3):

you can try:
`$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']`

quote:

> Filesystem- (not document root-) based path to the current script, after the server has done any virtual-to-real mapping. Note: As of PHP 4.3.2, `PATH_TRANSLATED` is no longer set implicitly under the Apache 2 SAPI in contrast to the situation in Apache 1, where it's set to the same value as the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` server variable when it's not populated by Apache.
>   This change was made to comply with the CGI specification that PATH_TRANSLATED should only exist if `PATH_INFO` is defined. Apache 2 users may use `AcceptPathInfo = On` inside `httpd.conf` to define `PATH_INFO`

source:
[php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath).

`realpath(".")` returns your document root.

You can call realpath with your specific path. Note that it will *NOT* work if the target folder or file does not exist. In such case it will return false, which could be useful for testing if a file exists.

In my case I needed to specify a path for a new file to be written to disk, and the solution was to append the path relative to document root:

`$filepath = realpath(".") . "/path/to/newfile.txt";`

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: It works, and I think it's the best solution here. By reading the documentation, I'm not able to understand why and how it works.
`realpath() [...] resolves references to /./, /../  [...] and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.` 
Fine, but `.` means current directory, so if you pass it as parameter, how it's resolved to root' current directory? What I'm missing?

Comment: I couldn't make this work. It shows C:/xampp/htdocs/shipping/styles.css in the devtools, but if I open it, it redirects to http://localhost/shipping/shipment-details.php/C:/xampp/htdocs/shipping/styles.css which is totally unclear, why.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $pathInPieces = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , __FILE__);
echo $pathInPieces[0].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

This example assumes you always know where the apache root folder is '/var/www/' and you are trying to find the next folder path (e.g. '/var/www/my_website_folder'). Also this works from a script or the web browser which is why there is additional code.

**Code PHP7**

```
function getHtmlRootFolder(string $root = '/var/www/') {

    // -- try to use DOCUMENT_ROOT first --
    $ret = str_replace(' ', '', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    $ret = rtrim($ret, '/') . '/';

    // -- if doesn't contain root path, find using this file's loc. path --
    if (!preg_match("#".$root."#", $ret)) {
      $root = rtrim($root, '/') . '/';
      $root_arr = explode("/", $root);
      $pwd_arr = explode("/", getcwd());
      $ret = $root . $pwd_arr[count($root_arr) - 1];
    }

    return (preg_match("#".$root."#", $ret)) ? rtrim($ret, '/') . '/' : null;
}
```

**Example**

```
echo getHtmlRootFolder();
```

*Output:*

```
/var/www/somedir/
```

**Details:**

Basically first tries to get DOCUMENT_ROOT if it contains '/var/www/' then use it, else get the current dir (which much exist inside the project) and gets the next path value based on count of the $root path. Note: added rtrim statements to ensure the path returns ending with a '/' in all cases . It doesn't check for it requiring to be larger than /var/www/ it can also return /var/www/ as a possible response.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```php
realpath("../")
```

you can use this `../` param to point. It will point to 1 step back to your actual working file

Comment: This will return path, 1-level up from the _current_ file

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24338828/7478226

```
<base href="http://localhost/abc/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code. It allows for a user defined folder to be declared as $root on the first line.
It then gets the actual root using __FILE__.
This is exploded using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (so that it works on any system).
A loop creates a new array of just the parts before the $root is found.
$root is then pushed to the array.
The new array is imploded using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR again as the glue.
The result is stored in a new global named REAL_ROOT.

Let me know if it is any help, or any good!

```
$root = 'folder_you_want_as_root';
$currentDirectory = __FILE__;
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,__FILE__);
$newParts = [];
foreach($parts as $part){
    if($part==$root){
        break;
    }
    $newParts[] = $part;
}
$newParts[] = $root;
define('REAL_ROOT',implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$newParts));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm share how i resolve this problem. Maybe helpful for you.

I'm create new file "my-config.php" in my root folder. And add this code inside.

```
<?php define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
```

And i'm use composer. (You can google it for this.) My composer(composer.json) like this (for this question).

```
{
"files": [
    "my-config.php"
  ]
}
```

And call autoloader.php in all file. Because, my config file calling automaticly thanks to autoloader.

```
<?php require  __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php"; ?>
```

Now, since define is a constant that is defined once and cannot be changed again, ABSPATH will be determined as soon as my landing page loads and I will type ABSPATH whenever I want to use the root directory path.

Then i use everywhere "ABSPATH" for root path. For example i use xampp so my root path C://xampp/htdocs/

---

It works like this. Composer automatically loads the files and classes we write into composer.json. This is its intended use. Please ask google for more details.

Here, we have loaded the autoload.php and my-config.php file on the landing page. At this point, since our landing page will be located in the root directory, it will take the ABSPATH root directory path.

Of course, the root directory will be the path to the landing page. If your landing page is in another folder, then it will take the path of the folder it is in.