# css not working when header.php file included in other than root folder but working on root folder

Tags: php, html, css

I have a index.php file on my root folder and it has an header file included like

```
include 'include/header.php';
```

In that header.php i have following code at start...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dashboard.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

The above index.php is working fine on root folder but when i use it in other folder it then css is not working for same file...
if i use **abc/index.php** then css will not work for that file...

> Note : I have used ./ as well as / or nothing at all but its not working.

Comment: What is your directory structure? Where are the css files kept?

Comment: use your full path with your css and js files

Comment: is the first / in /css/main.css" really necessary? maybe just "css/main.css"

Comment: @NerdByDesign you should understand what it means to have a leading slash. I highly suggest to always use a leading slash and use the full path to the css/js files so you never have a problem from any directory structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **base** tag and change your code like this

```
<base href="http://localhost/abc/" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dashboard.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>
```

Comment: SOLVED..! Thank you very much Syam Mohan...
You saved my work as adding that base tag is worked...
All working fine..
Thanx Again...!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the dir `css` is but you need to change all of these urls

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

to absolute ones:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/root/wherever/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanx for reviewing my problem...
Actually Syam Mohan's answer worked for me...
Thanx to you also for your Valuable comment...