# PHP path starting /

Tags: php, authentication

In HTML you can set your href to "/folder/page" and the starting / would go to the root-directory of your web application (meaning it would start at www.yoursite.com) and move on from there.

Now, in PHP, can i do this? I am having a problem, since i have a file, that ALWAYS needs to start at the root, and then go a folder down. I can't use relative paths, since it will be included in other pages and of thus, i wouldn't know how many layers to go up before i was in the root directory.

I tried using "$_SESSION['DOCUMENT_ROOT']" but that gives me an address too far up the directory tree. For example (on a test site) i have this URL:
http://localhost:8888/kasseNet-BitBucet/

And i want THAT to be my root. Currently it's something like "Applications/Mamp/htdocs".

How can i achieve this? Obviously i could use an absolute path for this, but then it wouldn't be easy for me to launch it, since i would have to change it to not be on a localhost environment.

I have been googling my ass off, but i can't seem to find the right fit. It should be an easy task to accomplish.

For completeness sake, here is my structure:

(assuming we are in "root" - the localhost htdocs/site folder)
- Login
   *Authenticate.php
   *login.php
- Other
   *test.php
- default.php

Now, both "default.php" and "test.php" will **include** the authenticate.php. The authenticate.php will redirect to the login.php. Now, the problem is that if i include it in the default.php, my path in the Authenticate.php file to the login.php would be "Login/Authenticate.php". BUT, if i include it in the test.php, i would have to do "../Login/Authenticate.php". This illustrates the problem, and it only gets worse as the structure grows.

As you can imagine, it is for a login script where i include the authenticate file, that will redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in. All the examples i've found though, just uses a flat structure with no extra directories, so they don't have that problem.

Hoping for some help, been stuck for days thinking of a solution xD

Thank you in advance.
Best Regards
/JBJ

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668776/get-root-directory-path-of-a-php-project/ Mark answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the root URL and append whatever you want after it.

`$root = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';`

---

If your path is something like `http://localhost:8888/kasseNet-BitBucet/path1/path2/index.php` you have to **define** `kasseNet-BitBucet` as your root directory. PHP cannot undrestand that `kasseNet-BitBucet` is your root directory and `path1` for example is not.

So:

```
$my_root_dir = 'kasseNet-BitBucet';
$root = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $my_root_dir;
```

Comment: Well that works, thanks! Still seems a little weird that PHP doesn't have a more built-in feature to achieve this. But i'll make this do, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The answer is correct and  i will accept it :) I just had to wait a minute before it allows me to do it. Thanks a lot Sky!