# I want to set base path in php to include every where

Tags: php

I write the following code in php but it says 'include_once(models/Uploader.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'.

```
if(isset($photo)){
        include_once "models/Uploader.class.php";
        $uploader = new Uploader('photo');

        if(!is_dir("contacts/$owner"))
            if(!mkdir("contacts/$owner", 0777, true)){
                die('Failed to create folders');
            }
 }
```

Please help me!

Comment: Where is your folder structure?

Comment: poss dupe, or at least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668776/get-root-directory-path-of-a-php-project