# Upload multiple images returning false

Tags: php, file-upload

Trying to upload multiple images to a folder choose from a drop down list. I managed to make it work perfectly but all of a sudden it stopped working. The `move_uploaded_file()` function returns false. I have no idea why. I used `echo` to print out path and its 100% correct. I also checked destination directory permissions (set to 777).

I'm no expert in php, I followed multiple tutorials and guides to come up with the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/MobileApp/Portal/favicon.png">
        <script>(function(e,t,n){var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2")})(document,window,0);</script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ font: 14px sans-serif; padding-left:15px; padding-top:15px; text-align: center;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) & isset($_POST['s1'])){
        $choice = $_POST['s1'];
        $fixedPath = 'MobileApp/Images/';
        $slash = "/";

        // Count total files
        $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

        // Looping all files
        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $chosenPath = $fixedPath.$choice.$slash.$i;
            //$chosenPath = $fixedPath.$choice.$slash.$filename;
            echo $chosenPath;
            // Upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $chosenPath)){
                echo "Good"; 
            }
                else {
                    echo "bad";
                    echo $FILES['files']['error'];
                }

            //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file'],$chosenPath/.$_FILES['tmp_name']);
        }
    } 
    else { 
        echo "Please choose a folder";
    }

    ?>

        <p>
        <legend>Files Upload</legend>
        <div class="box">

        <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' style="text-align: center">
            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
            <label for="file">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
                    <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z" />
                </svg>
                <span>Choose a file&hellip;</span>
            </label>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload' class="btn btn-warning" padding-top="15px" style="width:500px">
            <BR>
            <BR>
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label>User's folder:</label>
                    <form method='post' action='' name='s1'>
                        <select name="s1" style="width:400px">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
                            <?php
            foreach(glob(dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*') as $filename){ 

            //foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/MobileApp/Images/') as $filename){

            $filename = basename($filename);
            echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
            }
            ?>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </p>


    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

I have done some tweaking in my code and narrowed down the issue to this line of code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][i], $chosenPath)
```

but can't see my issue..

Comment: I can see there are nested form tags in your code. Nested forms will not work.

Comment: @VinayPatil but it worked before. I also have nested form in another php file and it works..

Comment: @VinayPatil I removed the nested form but still the same issue. any other ideas?

Comment: how are you getting values in the dropdown?

Comment: Im using this : foreach(glob())...  2nd part of the code posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only change is needed here

```
$chosenPath = $fixedPath.$choice.$slash.$filename;
```

instead of

```
$chosenPath = $fixedPath.$choice.$slash.$i;
```

the second argument for the `move_uploaded_file` should be a destination filename. Only that one change worked for me.

One more thing that you need to provide the destination directory path from the `root` directory, that means **`$fixedPath = 'MobileApp/Images/';`** this should be a path from root directory like **`/var/www/html/../../MobileApp/Images/`** (it's only an example your actual directory path can be different) check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668853/1483629) to find the relative path of the destination directory

Comment: I just tested that. Didn't work. however, I took the php file from the sub directory and put it on root folder. surprisingly it worked. So no I'm thinking maybe permissions? my php file is set to 755 and destination folder is 777.

Comment: I don't think so it's a permission issue. It might be the directory path issue. Can you share `$chosenPath` value also check that path is correct and exist?

Comment: Also, share the path of the PHP file, it should be inside the `MobileApp/Images/` directory.

Comment: /MobileApp/Images/5/4.jpeg thats echo result for chosenPath.

Comment: Ok, then `/MobileApp/Images/5` exist in your directory right? which you select from dropdown.

Comment: Yes it does. I can access it from the browser normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196914/discussion-between-vinay-patil-and-saeed-joul).