# Include cant find directory PHP

Tags: php, path, include

i make MVC application (Without frameworks).
I try to include models from folder 'models' in controller, in folder controller.

```
include("/models/tasks_model.php");
```

But i get error:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/models/tasks_model.php' for inclusion (include_path='.') in ...controller\create_task_controller.php on line 3
```

And

```
Warning: include(/models/tasks_model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...\controller\create_task_controller.php on line 3
```

Comment: Anything starting with a slash looks for the file starting from the system root directory, not the project root directory.

Comment: If you haven't already, it might be worth your while to spend some time familiarizing yourself with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and autoloading - this will greatly facilitate building and maintaining your application.

Comment: @aynber , im understand, how i can use project root ?

Comment: Hey, can you plz show more of your project?  Also, plz show where all the files you are using are located.

Comment: @KompTip, what anyber appears to suggesting, is to remove the beginning forward slash. In this way your include will begin at the directory the script is in.

Comment: have a look at [get root directory of PHP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668776/get-root-directory-path-of-a-php-project)

Comment: I have project root.
In project root i have folders: 
Controllers
 And Models.
In folder "Controllers" i have controller. 
To this controller i need include model from folder "Models".

Comment: Where is your main file?  (The one in your question) @KompTip

Comment: Maybe I did not write it correctly.
I have two folders.  In one folder - Controller ( File 1 )
In second folder - Models ( File 2 ) 
I need include File 2 in File 1, Folders are not inside each other.

Comment: So the file that gives the errors is in the controller folder?

Comment: Root/Controller/Controller.php and 
Root/Models/Model.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your PHP paths

```
include("../models/tasks_model.php");
```

When you use this code:

```
include("/models/tasks_model.php");
```

It looks from the start of your disk because it an absolute path.

`../` Goes back one folder from where your file is.

Comment: Can you tell me what this code returns? `echo __DIR__;`

Comment: Full way starting from disk

Comment: So it doesn't start at /root/?