# php include function with css stylesheet outsie the root folder

Tags: php, html, css

i have a website with 1 CSS file. i use PHP include function for the menu and footer of the website. so if i want to change the menu and the footer i can do it in 1 file menu.php instead of going through 100 pages.

I created 4 folders for organizing articles by their subject.

the question is now menu.php has the css file link index.css
but inside the articles folders it should be ../index.css (because the css file is on root folder) and the css isn't working on the articles.

should i create a new menu.PHP. with ../index.css and put it inside each articles folder?
or can i add a second ../index.css link inside the main menu.php file.

Comment: Search for "relative path" and set your files as described. One solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668776/get-root-directory-path-of-a-php-project

Comment: i added this: <?php include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/home1/readlcom/public_html/menu.php'); ?> but it's not working the css file isn't loaded. the path is correct.

Comment: now tried this : <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menu.php";  ?> and only the html is working