# Absolute paths with file_exists and glob

Tags: php

Here's a simplified structure of files that I use in this case:

```
- core
  - ajax.php
- images
  - image.jpg
class.php
```

Ajax.php includes class.php - that is all fine.

In class.php I'm trying to use `file_exists()` in order to check if file exists:

```php
$path = '/images/image.jpg';
file_exists($path);
```

This returns **false** unless I add `..` in front of the path

```php
$path = '../images/image.jpg';
```

I'm guessing it's because the working directory is `/core` but I thought using the slash at the beginning of `/images` would "tell" PHP to search from the top level. I started playing with `dirname(__FILE__)` and attached it to the path:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/images/image.jpg';
```

Which results in: `/Websites/PG/core/images/image.jpg` but the image is still not found. Not sure if this could help but because of nature of the domain of this website, we had to include the following code in the htaccess file in the root of our server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/Websites/PG/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Websites/PG/$1 [L]
```

And I wonder if this is the cause of the problem because other websites never had problems with those functions or relative/absolute paths.

Any pointers as to what to change here would be gold.

Comment: "`but I thought using the slash at the beginning of /images would "tell" PHP to search from the top level.`" No. This is not how it happens. The `/` at the start tells PHP to work from the root directory of the file system, not the hosting domain system.

Comment: Also explore here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668776/get-root-directory-path-of-a-php-project

Comment: @Martin not sure if I understand. I want php to ingnore the `Websites/PG` because it's "beyond" root of the website but `dirname(__FILE__)` does include it. Is it because of the htaccess?  If I run `echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` in `test.php` I only get `/`

Comment: No. `.htaccess` works only on the *website* , your PHP works purely on the system *filepath*. These are completely different and one will not effect the other.

Comment: Please show us your absolute pathing from your root domain Letter to your images.jpg ; for example.

Comment: Also what value does `print $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` actually give you on website?

Comment: The absolute path would be `pg.com/images/image.jpg`   the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` gives me `/` only slash

Comment: No, the absolute path is from the root drive letter; such as `C:\documentz\files\something\images\image.jpg`

Comment: It's a shared hosting, so it would be `public_html/Websites/PG/images/image.jpg`

Comment: No, Moseley, the path you have given me is the path to the root of the webserver not the root of the filepath system. what does `print_r(__FILE__);` give you when you run PHP?

Comment: When I run this in `ajax.php` (so the file in subfolder), it shows `/Websites/PG/core/ajax.php`

Comment: What I don't get is why using `/images/image.jpg` in `ajax.php` with `file_exists()` doesn't work, I thought the slash at the beginning would mean the search is performed from root

Comment: `I thought the slash at the beginning would mean the search is performed from root` It is, but it's from the filepath root rather than the website root. You may need to check if the PHP has access to the file itself; ie that `image.jpg` has the ownership and permissions of the PHP handler to be allowed to run it; can you run [fileperms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php) to see who owns the image file and if this owner is the same as the PHP handler

Comment: I checked using `fileowner("../images/image.php")` but it didn't return anything. I doubt it's permission problem because everything works if I add the two dots in front of the path like `file_exists("../images/image.jpg")`. The two dots are problematic though. If I call the `class.php` not in the subfolder, the two dots pose a problem

Comment: By the way the `print_r(__FILE__)` in a different website shows `/core/ajax.php`. If it's not the htaccess, could it be that the domain is directed to our server by IP and then we use this htaccess to point to a folder

Comment: @Martin have you had any more thoughts? I realised if I include this in the php functions `file_exists('/WebsitesLive/PG/'.$path)` then it's fine but this would become something hardcoded that may change if I change the folder

Comment: I think you may have an issue with your filepathing but I have not looked into this further. You need lots of error logging or output of various PHP generated pathings on your script and see how these compare to the actual pathing on your server device.

Comment: I'm going to write an e-mail to the hosting provider and see if they can shed any more lights on this. Thanks @Martin

Comment: you need to do some debugging work on the code yourself. The information is there (lots of error logs or print_R of variables) but I can't tell you what that is from here because I'm not on your system.